# How to connect windows7 Git to dreamhost server Git

Tags: windows, git, dreamhost

I am planning to use **Git** as **SCM** tool, the repository I am using is **Dreamhost**.

I'm trying to connect **Git** from my **local machine** (Windows 7) to the **Git** on my **dreamhost** server. I have installed `git version 1.7.6 n` both the **Dreamhost** and my **local machine**.

Note: I have tried the **dreamhost** docs for **git**, but they are for **Unix** machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instruction for [Git Dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Git) from a msysgit bash session: 
at least `ssh-keygen` is available.

The only "trick" on Windows is to define `%HOME%` (or `$HOME` in bash): that variable isn't defined by default, and your ssh session will look for `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: Hi Von, I am unable to run the ssh-copy-id command. Other than that the document worked just fine.

Comment: @Akash: I confirm, the msysgit bash session doesn't include `ssh-copy-id`, sadly.

Comment: Hey Von ,

Thanks a lot ...Was able to do the trick by using "scp" to copy the rsa keys as authorised keys for the server.

Comment: @Akash: that is similar to what you see in http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/#more-32